# Отключение объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Задаю скорее всего очень простой вопрос, базовый, однако ни где не смог найти его решение.
Мне нужно отключить объект на котором висит скрипт, я могу сделать

```
publc GameObject molot;
molot.SetActive(false);
```

Это безусловно будет работать, но, зачем указывать лишнюю переменную и переносить туда объект, если скрипт висит на том самом объекте, который мне нужно выключить(включать не надо). Наверняка есть способ указать юнити, что нужно отключить именно тот объект, на котором и находится скрипт

Comment: просто в методе, в котором надо это сделать пишется `SetActive(false);`. По умолчанию метод неявно добавляет в начало `this`, т.е. `this.SetActive(false);`, что указывает на текущий объект

Comment: Я тоже так подумал но это не работает, он ругается на false

Comment: как именно ругается на false?

Comment: error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'false' is a keyword

Comment: покажите весь код, который пытались написать просто через `setActive`. скорее всего где-то синтаксическая ошибка, не более

Comment: `using System.Collections;`
`using System.Collections.Generic;`
`using UnityEngine;`

`public class Help_Flag : MonoBehaviour`
`{`
    `SetActive(false);`
`}`

Comment: Так, и почему же вы используете метод вне другого метода?))

Comment: Собственный объект это `gameObject`(с маленькой буквы). `this` это сам скрипт, его тоже можно отключать, через `this.enable =`(галочка на компоненте в инспекторе).

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: К тому же вам не обязательно создавать новую переменную. Вы можете сделать как-то так: `GameObject.Find("НазваниеОбъекта").gameObject.SetActive(true);` (плохой пример)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрипт, который висит на объекте, хранит ссылку на самого себя, которую можно получить словом `this`. Если вы хотите изменить какую-либо переменную в скрипте из этого же скрипта, то получаете подобный код: `this.variable = ...`, однако `this` подставляется по умолчанию, поэтому вы можете просто писать `variable = ...`

Имея ссылку на скрипт, вы можете получить объект, на котором висит этот скрипт с помощью `[ссылка_на_скрипт].gameObject`. Так как this подставляется самостоятельно, то чтобы получить объект, на котором висит скрипт из этого же скрипта вы просто пишите `gameObject`.

Чтобы отключить объект:

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

Чтобы отключить скрипт на этом же объекте:

```
this.enabled = false;
ИЛИ
enabled = false; // Опять же this подставляется самостоятельно
```

Обязательно писать this нужно только, например, в конструкторах, если происходит конфликт имен аргумента конструктора и поля класса:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public int variable;
    public MyClass (int variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
}
```